# How to implement function overloading with different argument types in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, overloading

Suppose python supported function overloading, how would we define overloaded functions for adding two numbers and concatenating two strings?
I just want to know how do we assign a particular data type to a parameter in the function definition or will it depend on the arguments given in the function call.
Would it be like this:

```
    def num(a=int,b=int):
        return a+b
    def strng(a=str,b=str):
        return a+b
```

Comment: show example code. Cheers.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing

Comment: I know that function overloading in languages like C++ and Java can be done in two ways: different number of parameters or different data types of parameters. I want to know about the second one.

Comment: In brief: if a function performs differently depending on its arguments' type, it has to check the arguments' types with `isinstance()` or `type()` before computing the results.

Comment: @DyZ: no, that's bad advice, in many cases it's more Pythonic to use try...except ladder.

Comment: @smci Any supporting evidence to this claim? How about the case when the alternative behavior does not raise an exception? Say, I define function that performs integer division // if both parameters are integer and true division if not?

Comment: DyZ you can easily think up examples. Things that will throw an exception: Integers and floats don't have string methods like `find, lower, startswith`, and strings don't have `is_integer` or property `real`. Yes obviously overloaded operators like `+,*,==,<,>` will not raise an exception so you have to fall back on explicit `isinstance/type`.

Comment: @smci checking arguments types for dispatch is perfectly pythonic, and most often the best way to handle this case (when implementing the function as a method is not possible of course).

Comment: @vaanchitkaul you maye want to have a look at the various "multimethods" packages or snippets, ie this example from GvR itself : https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=101605

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: when there's a method call and corresponding exception that can distinguish the arg types, it gives shorter clearer code to do that.

Comment: @smci Sorry but nope (been here, done that...) - first because there are _many_ not-that-cornerish corner cases where relying on `AttributeError` or such just won't work, then because the cost of an exception handler (when it's triggered) is quite high compared to a typecheck. There are indeed cases where EAFP is a better approach than LBYL (specially when dealing with non-atomic operations and concurrency issues), but this is not one. FWIW even the BDFL uses typecheck for this exact kind of problems, cf https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=101605

Comment: Bruno the tiny performance penalty for exception is generally fine unless you're in a performance-critical inner loop. Many expert Python users recommend it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

python is dynamically typed language. Hence, type checks are not strictly enforced. In defining a function, you can define an optional `type` for the parameters.

`def function(a:int=0, b:int=0): return a + b`

The type definition here really does nothing peculiar but probably helps with IDE autocompletion. You can pass in a string and you won't get any errors but it'll definitely throw an error when adding a `number` to a `string`.